# Go Language Prometheus Alert message in Grafana

Tags: go, kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager

i write expression which send me alert in Telegram.
now I want to parse it with `prometheus` alert manager

This is my code

```
{{ define "test" }}
{{ range .Alerts }}
test_1 : {{ .Annotations.query_value.var }}
test_2 : {{ .Status }}
test_3 : {{ .ValueString }}
test_4 : {{ .Labels.alertname }}

{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

output is :

```
test_1 : \[ var='C0' metric='loki-loki-distributed-ingester-0' labels={pod=loki-loki-distributed-ingester-0} value=6.975442944e+09 \]
test_2 : firing 
test_3 : \[ var='C0' metric='loki-loki-distributed-ingester-0' labels={pod=loki-loki-distributed-ingester-0} value=6.975442944e+09 \]  
test_4 : map\[alertness Usage - Of Machine Grafana_folder:test-dev-memory-usage ]
```

i want to print

```
test_1 :  value=6.975442944e+09
test_2 : firing
test_3 : value=6.975442944e+09 \] 
test_4 : Memory Usage - Of Machine \
```

my be stack is not good choice for this question but , i hope someone can helm me :) Good day